# How to Paste screen shot in mac 10.9?

Tags: macos, keyboard

Im using MAC 10.9 , really don't know about using short cut keys. i know how to take screen shot cmmd shift 3 , thanks to Samkit, but i dont know how to paste that screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

The screen shot is simply put on the Desktop for me.